# Retrofit retry request with callback

Tags: android, retrofit2, interceptor

I want to catch a specific status code globally, do something and then retry the request when the something is done.

I have written an interceptor to retry the request upon receiving that status code.

The request itself is being retried and is successful, but the original callback is not called in that case.

What do I need to add to make sure the original callback is called ?

```
public class LoginResponseInterceptor implements Interceptor, SocketListener {
    private Set<Chain> requestsToRetry = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void onLoggedIn() {
        List<Chain> requestsToResend = new ArrayList<>(requestsToRetry);
        for (Chain chain : requestsToResend) {
            try {
                Request request = chain.request();
                Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();
                String token = getToken();
                if (token != null) {
                    Headers headers = request.headers().newBuilder().set("Authorization",token).build();
                    builder.headers(headers);
                }
                Request newRequest = builder.build();
                chain.proceed(newRequest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        chainSet.removeAll(requestsToResend);
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (response.code() == 401) {
            chainSet.add(chain);
            tryRelogin();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```